# How to write a group of substitude (la->lb), (lb->lc), (lc->la) as a regular expression

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I need to do it in vim (MacVim) and use it in one line.

```
z.a2=cross(z.b, z.c)(z.b1, z.c1);
```

Became the ofllowing line:

```
z.b2=cross(z.c, z.a)(z.c1, z.a1);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a dictionary:

```
:let replacements = {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'a'}
:s/[abc]r\@!/\=replacements[submatch(0)]/g
```

The `r\@!` prevents the `c` of `cross` being changed.

Add a `%` in front of the `s` if you want to do it on the whole file rather than just the current line.  Note that this will change ANY 'a', 'b' or 'c' on the line, including those within words (e.g. the `c` in `cross`).  To restrict this, you could change the pattern to `\<[abc]\>`, but that would fail to match where you have `a2`, so that would suggest: `\<\([abc]\)\d*\>` (and replace the `submatch(0)` with `submatch(1)`.  If you just want to match where you have the `z` preceding, this is easy:

```
:let replacements = {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'a'}
:s/z\.\zs[abc]/\=replacements[submatch(0)]/g
```

See:

```
:help Dictionary
:help :substitute
:help :s\=
:help \@!
:help \zs
:help \(\)
:help \<
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner?

```
%s/\.a/*b*/g | %s/\.b/*c*/g | %s/\.c/*a*/g | %s/\*a\*/.a/g | %s/\*b\*/.b/g | %s/\*c\*/.c/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for: `z\.(a)(2)=cross\(z\.(b), (z\.c)\)\(z\.b(1), (z\.c1)\);`

Replace with: `z.$3$2=cross($4, z.$1)($6, z.$1$5);`